# Is there a 'better' way to find files from a list in a directory tree

Tags: bash, file-system

I have created a list of files using `find`, `foundlist.lst`.

The find command is simply `find . -type f -name "<search_pattern>" > foundlist.lst`

I would now like to use this list to find copies of these files in other directories.

The 'twist' in my requirements is that I want to search only for the 'base' of the file name. I don't want to include the extension in the search.

Example:

`./sort.cc` is a member of the list. I want to look for all files of the pattern `sort.*`

Here is what I wrote. It works. It seems to me that there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
./findfiles.sh foundfiles.lst /usr/bin/temp

#!/bin/bash
# findfiles.sh
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Need two arguments"
    echo "usage: findfiles <filelist> <dir_to_search>"
else
    filename=$1
    echo "$filename"
    while read -r line; do
        name=$line
        # change './file.ext' to 'file.*'
        search_base=$( echo ${name} | sed "s%\.\/%%" | sed "s/\..*/\.\*/" )
        find $2 -type f -name $search_base
    done < $filename
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In think you can do three things to improve your script(s):

- Try to avoid complexity O(N^2)
- Try to reuse intermediate results
- Try to reduce extra process calls

The first aspects comes about because you compare the *ALL* files in the first directory to *ALL* files in the second directory. If both directories scale more or less by N you will have a rather slow algorithm for really large directories.

The second aspect relates to calling `find` again and again instead of calling it once and then using the output of the call for comparison.

The third aspect relates to e.g. calling `sed` twice in a pipe for something that can be done by the `bash` itself.

I have prepared a slightly different approach which is far from elegant and/or perfect but which may give you some ideas. The key features are:

- It only calls `find` once for each directory and stores the result in files.
- Instead of a nested loop (with `find` being the inner loop) it uses `sort` with complexity O(NlogN) to find the matches.
- It focuses on the basenames of the filenames for comparison. Only for the result the "long" names are looked up again.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1=$1
dir2=$2

# list all files in dir a using format "filename filepath"
find $dir1 -type f -printf "%f %p\n" > dir1.lst

# sort filename portion alphabetically and append " 1" as source
cat dir1.lst | while read filename filepath
do
    echo ${filename%.*}
done | sort -u | while read filename 
do
    echo "$filename 1"
done > dir1base.lst

# list all files in dir b using format "filename filepath"
find $dir2 -type f -printf "%f %p\n" > dir2.lst

# sort filename portion alphabetically and append " 2" as source
cat dir2.lst | while read filename filepath
do
    echo ${filename%.*}
done | sort -u | while read filename 
do
    echo "$filename 2"
done > dir2base.lst

# now merge the two lists together; sort them by filename first and by source second
last=""
sort -k 1 -k 2  -u dir1base.lst dir2base.lst | while read filename dir
do
    # if we find an entry from source 2 that had the same filename from source 1 just before we have a match
    if [[ $dir -eq 2 && $last == $filename ]] ; then
        # output match
        echo $filename
    fi
    last=$filename
done | while read match 
do
    # now grep for matches in both original files
    echo "*** File(s)"
    grep $match dir1.lst
    echo "*** match file(s)"
    grep $match dir2.lst
    echo "---"
done
```

Note that the output loop still has complexity O(M^2) with the inner loop being in the `grep` call. However, in this case M scales with the number of matches and not the original input size. The former should be considerably smaller.

Also note the first `find` command will have to be adapted to be more selective than it is now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling sed twice, you can use Parameter expansion in bash:

```
search_base=${name%.*}'.*'    # Remove everything after the last dot (included).
search_base=${search_base#./} # Remove the leading dot and slash.
```

Keep in mind, though, that some files can have no extension.

Comment: The two sed scripts perform the following, remove the leading ./, then remove the trailing extension and replace with .*. So I can use the second line of your answer, but not the first. Correct?

Comment: @KeithSmith: Sorry, my mistake. Fixed.